# android singleTask/singleInstance issue

Tags: android, launchmode

I'm designing a game for android which I want to have only one instance of it.

the game has the main activity which I called GameActivity and another activity I called CreateAccountActivity.

I defined int the manifest the GameActivity to be `android:launchMode="singleTask"`.

when the application starts for the first time, i start the CreateAccoutActivity using `startActivityForResult` method.

the issue is, when I hit the home button and then start my application, nothing happens (from the user perspective, but I see from the logs that CreateAccountActivity is destroyed, GameActivity `onActivityResult` is called and then it destroyed too (it gets `RESULT_CANCEL` off course.

here are the logs:

```
12-28 14:30:11.910: V/WindowManager(24745): Dsptch > Window{47ce9868 com.sec.android.app.twlauncher/com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.Launcher paused=false}
12-28 14:30:11.910: V/InputDevice(24745): ID[0]=0(0) Dn(0=>1)
12-28 14:30:11.973: D/dalvikvm(7770): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 313 objects / 12648 bytes in 25ms
12-28 14:30:12.004: V/InputDevice(24745): ID[0]=0(0) Up(1=>0)
12-28 14:30:12.039: D/dalvikvm(7770): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 88 objects / 2680 bytes in 25ms
12-28 14:30:12.110: D/dalvikvm(7770): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 24 objects / 864 bytes in 25ms
12-28 14:30:12.157: V/WindowManager(24745): Dsptch > Window{47ce9868 com.sec.android.app.twlauncher/com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.Launcher paused=false}
12-28 14:30:12.157: I/ActivityManager(24745): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.*****.tq/.GameActivity }
12-28 14:30:12.161: D/Launcher.Workspace(7770): WorkspaceDraw: Workspace drawWallpaperImage()
12-28 14:30:12.168: I/CreateAccountActivity(9369): onDestroy
12-28 14:30:12.172: I/Launcher(7770): onPause()
12-28 14:30:12.184: W/Launcher(7770): WallpaperManager setVisibility visible true
12-28 14:30:12.203: I/GameActivity(9369): Game activity onActivityResult
12-28 14:30:12.203: I/GameActivity(9369): disconnecting from main server
12-28 14:30:12.203: I/ConnectionManager(9369): Disconnecting...
12-28 14:30:12.207: I/GameActivity(9369): Game activity onNewIntent is called
12-28 14:30:12.215: I/Launcher(7770): onWindowFocusChanged(false)
12-28 14:30:12.219: I/Launcher(7770): onResume(). mIsNewIntent : false
12-28 14:30:12.219: E/Launcher(7770): MTP-LAUNCHER: media scanning not yet finished . 
12-28 14:30:12.219: I/Launcher(7770): onResume() ended
12-28 14:30:12.219: I/Launcher(7770): onWindowFocusChanged(true)
12-28 14:30:12.223: W/InputManagerService(24745): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@47d9fa18
12-28 14:30:12.227: D/Launcher.Workspace(7770): WorkspaceDraw: Workspace drawWallpaperImage()
12-28 14:30:12.235: I/GameActivity(9369): Game activity destroyed
12-28 14:30:12.762: D/BatteryService(24745): update start
12-28 14:30:12.770: D/BatteryService(24745): updateBattery level:100 scale:100 status:5 health:2 present:true voltage: 4240 temperature: 360 technology: Li-ion AC powered:false USB powered:true icon:17302163
12-28 14:30:12.801: I/StatusBarPolicy(24745): BAT. status:5 health:2
12-28 14:30:12.801: D/WifiService(24745): ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED pluggedType: 2
12-28 14:30:13.231: W/Launcher(7770): WallpaperManager setVisibility visible false
12-28 14:30:13.375: D/Launcher.Workspace(7770): WorkspaceDraw: Workspace drawWallpaperImage()
```

for simplicity I describe it like that:
Activity A = MAIN - singleTask
Activity B = (undefined - standard)

A startsForResult B  -> home button  -> game launch button -> B destroyed -> A onActivityResult is called -> A destroyed -> game launch button -> A startstForResult B ...

*EDIT*

I now doubt if I need to use singleTask at all.

Is it true, that no matter from where I start my activity by the android and not by an intent I coded, android will always restart my app and there won't be any multiple instances of my activities ?

if that's the case, anything is goo -ood :)

Comment: Please post your manifest. The behaviour you are describing is strange.

Answer (score 0):

From the activity documentation

> a "singleTask" activity may or may not have other activities above it
>   in the stack. If it does, it is not in position to handle the intent,
>   and the intent is dropped. (Even though the intent is dropped, its
>   arrival would have caused the task to come to the foreground, where it
>   would remain.)

When you click the game launch, creating this `Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.*****.tq/.GameActivity`
the GameActivity(A) is trying to handle the intent in onNewIntent(). You could put a Log.d("GameActivity", "onNewIntent is called") to verify this. (B) is simply destroyed before a result can be set.

Maybe you could setResult() in CreateAccountActivity.onDestroy() so that you can handle it in the GameActivity?

Comment: i have a Log.i("GameActivity", "onNewIntent is called") as you can see at the code in my question. it comes after B is destroyed.